# css in resolution 1920x1080 in the chrome background on elements

Tags: css, google-chrome, resolution

The must amazing problem with css in these Conditions:

- chrome only
- resolution 1920x1080

In the firefox work fine, in other resolution work fine.

What is the problem: the background color come on list elements:

[image]

My css code:

```
  body {
    background: #2D2F39;
    color: #9E9A98;
    font-size: 10pt;
  }
  .liner{
        margin-top: 1em;
        background: #353C48 ;
    }

 .line-item {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) ;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
        padding: 5px 1em;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .line-item h3{
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 12pt;
        color: #C21F39 ;
        padding: 2px 5px 0;
        font-weight: normal;
    }
    .line-item h3:hover{
        color: #fff;
        /*border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;*/
    }
    .line-item p{
        color: #bbb;
        margin-top: 0;
    }
```

html for example:

```
<div   class="liner ">
            <div   class="line-item" ><a  href="#/questions/General-RCE-quesions" class=""><h3 >
                        # General RCE quesions
                    </h3></a>
                <p >
                    <span  class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span> 
                    The general question about Reverse code engineering here... [Debugging, Cracking, Unpacking]</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> notes: I use `webpack` for this, and when try to inspect element it's
>   fixing temporary.

You can try this:

https://webscene.ir/#/tools

Change some page in this section with chrome and resolution 1920x1080.

Comment: Not able to produce this problem. Looks good to me

Comment: @DhavalPanchal Wow, Some people report me this bug. and i have this :(

Comment: Do you have url where I can see this bug?

Comment: @DhavalPanchal it's random in left menu try to change page question or tutorial or challenage or tools.

Comment: Please create a fiddle for same or paste your HTML code

Comment: @AmbujKhanna added html

Comment: @A1Gard Please elaborate in which element you are getting background color? What expected behavior should be and what is coming up?

Comment: Still working fine for me @A1Gard

Comment: @AmbujKhanna same as picture the elements and text of them not show complete as usual.

Comment: it is working fine for me. Might be some special CSS applied by browser on specific scenario.